# TypeORM creates double tables - is it by design?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am a newbie to TypeORM. In a NestJS + TypeORM/postgres app, I have these three very simple entities

```
@Entity()
export class Book extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  year: string;
}


@Entity()
export class Author extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;
}

@Entity()
export class Genre extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

As you see, no relations so far, no custom table or column names, plain default entities.

When I start the app (with `synchronize: true`) and look into pgAdmin, I can see that the `author` and `genre` tables get created along with duplicate tables, sharing same set of columns:

```
author
author_entity
genre
genre_entity
book
```

Is it so by design?
What is the reason `book` entity doesn't get a duplicate. If this is unexpected behavior, any clue where I should look into?

Comment: It's not expected behavior, no. Did you by any chance originally name your Author and Genre entities "AuthorEntity" and "GenreEntity"? I could be wrong, but my guess is that the sync doesn't delete old tables just because the entity was renamed.

Comment: Yep, that was the clue. And so when I removed the dist folder, things got straight. Feel free to add your comment as an answer, I wiill accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you probably originally named your Author and Genre entities `AuthorEntity` and `GenreEntity`. I don't think `synchronize` will automatically remove database tables whose entity was renamed; it'll just create a new table.

So a simple solution would be to drop the tables in your database and re-run the sync fresh, and you should no longer have those orphaned tables.

Comment: As in theoriginal comment - the previous state was still persisting in the stale compilation, so `rm -rf dist` solved the problem. Thanks for the hint!